# Portainer - How to get the run options working

Tags: docker, jupyter, portainer

On https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html there is a code snippet:

```
docker run --rm -p 10000:8888 -e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes -v "$PWD":/home/jovyan/work jupyter/datascience-notebook:9b06df75e445
```

For Portainer, I have a question about the implementation of this line; download the image and start the container - no problem.

Only I can't find a place where I can implement:

```
-e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB = yes
```

Do you have the solution? Thank you for the effort.

Comment: I can't understand your question. You asking what `-e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB = yes` is supposed to do?

Comment: I agree, the question is a bit confusing. if you just run that exact `docker run` code, it'll include that environment variable. I've never used Jupyter but just looking at the variable it appears to toggle it's enabled/disabled state, lol. I'm not sure how you're tying this into Portainer though?